# What is the most efficient way to display tenth of a second with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time

I am writing a small application with clock that sicplay date and time with tenths of a second. What is the most efficient to do this ?

I have already wrote this but I doubt that this is a good solution :

```
var today=new Date();
var mini=today.getMilliseconds();
mini = mini %1000;

if(mini < 100) mini = 0;
else{
    mini = ""+mini;
    mini = mini.substring(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Math.round(new Date().getMilliseconds() / 100)
```

BTW `mini % 1000` is redundant, milliseconds never exceed 1000.

Answer (score 1):

```
((new Date()).getMilliseconds()/100).toFixed(0);
```

Note that this returns a string, not an integer. However, the number is rounded.